# Getting Price before sending Twilio message

Tags: .net, api, rest, twilio

I am using the [Twilio .NET Helper Library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) and want to be able to determine the price of a call or SMS message before I actually send it.  For example, if it is a SMS message that will go to a UK number I want to know the price before actually sending the message.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Twilio offers their current international rates as a CSV file you can download. Find out where your SMS is headed to, then lookup the pricing information- http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/where-can-i-see-all-of-twilios-sms-pricing-in-one-place  AND http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/where-can-i-see-all-of-twilios-voice-pricing-in-one-place

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that should be a good alternative.

Comment: but,i don't know the operator,in many country,The price which in different operator is different,how to differentiate the phone number?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the SMS price before you send.
As the fee varies base on the carriers.

However, by using the twilio api call, you can get the "sent" price only if the message is "sent"

if the message is "queued", the price is NULL.